# Programmatically change ListBox DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox, datatemplate

Hey Guys I was just wandering if anyone can show me how to Programmatically change a ListBoxDataTemplate. So basically I have this DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" d:DesignWidth="446" Width="446" d:DesignHeight="108" Height="108">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding AccountTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="28" />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding AccountUsername}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Margin="0,33,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="24" />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding AccountWebsite}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Margin="0,61,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="24" />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding FolderID}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" Margin="0,96,0,-13" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="35" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="24" Opacity="0" Visibility="Collapsed" />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding AccountDate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,38,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now when the user sets a certain setting on the Settings page, The ListBox DataTemplate must change to this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1">
        <Grid toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" d:DesignWidth="446" Width="446" d:DesignHeight="108" Height="108">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding AccountTitle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="456" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="28" />
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="NoWrap" Text="{Binding AccountDate}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,38,0,0" FontFamily="Segoe WP" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Is it possble to do this? If so please someone help me.
Thanks!

Comment: I would use DataTriggers to do this, but I'm not sure if windows phone 8 supports them. If not, you might have to use a custom converter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of many ways, define two `DataTemplate`s in page Resources. Then you can set ListBox's `ItemTemplate` to any one of those two at run-time :

```
MyListBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)FindResource("DataTemplate2");
```

**UPDATE :**

Since, `FindResource()` function is not available in Windows Phone page, and as confirmed by OP this one works for him, so use following instead of above code :

```
MyListBox.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["DataTemplate2"];
```

Comment: After playing around, `ListBoxAll.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["DataTemplate2"];` worked. FindResource was unavailable but Thank you for pointing me to the right direction :D